# how to show full image on html5 canvas with border image and shadow?

Tags: html, canvas

I want to show full image using html 5 canvas with border image and shadown?

This is my code that I have done yet,Any help will be cause of pleasure to me

```js
const canvas1 = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
// Shadow
ctx1.shadowColor = 'red';
ctx1.shadowBlur = 20;
// tmpCanvas.height = 400;
 // canvas1.height = 500;
// Rectangle
//ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
//ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
 
  var tmpCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var tmpCtx = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');
tmpCtx.shadowColor = 'red';
tmpCtx.shadowBlur = 20;
//tmpCanvas.height=390;
//canvas1.height=550;
//canvas1.width=550;
 
   img.src = 'http://swiftinit.net/swiftapps/Custom/assets/images/frameimages/43378.png';

  tmpCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,img.width,img.height);

img.onload = function() {  
tmpCanvas.width  = this.width;
        tmpCanvas.height = 300;
alert(this.height)
}
ctx1.drawImage(tmpCanvas,10,10,tmpCanvas.width,tmpCanvas.height);
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/shadowBlur -->

<br>

<canvas id="mycanvas" style="position:fixed;right:20px"></canvas>
```

Comment: Please tell your problem more briefly

Comment: The issue is if you look at the pen the image does not show 100% with shadow. I need full 100% image with shadow(image is a border frame image). I tried setting height and width of canvas but does not work.

Comment: So you want to add border to canvas

Comment: yes also I need that canvas to be saved afterwards so CSS will not work, it needs be part of canvas.Its working in my codepen but if you visit my codepen the image is half cut.

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be done by CSS (the border part):

```
#mycanvas {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  /* Using  background image to add the border image */
  background-image: url('http://swiftinit.net/swiftapps/Custom/assets/images/frameimages/43378.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  /* Shadow */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 23px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 23px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 23px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  width: 267px; /* Same as image */
  height: 185px /* Same as image */
}
```

If you want to add an image in the canvas you can do it by adding an image element inside the canvas (actually anywhere will work because it takes the image by its id).

And displaying the image with Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var img = document.getElementById("imgPlaceHolder");
  //Image is scaled
  ctx.drawImage(img, 20, 14, 260, 125);
};
```

---

### UPDATE - 19 November 2019

Change This:

> HTML
>
> ```
> <canvas id="mycanvas" style="position:fixed;right:20px"></canvas>
> ```
>
> JS
>
> ```
> tmpCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,img.width,150);
> ```

To:

HTML

```
<canvas id="mycanvas" style="position:fixed;right:20px" height="200px"></canvas>
```

JS

```
tmpCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,img.width,150);
```

Not the perfect solution, but this works for me. The full image is displayed.
A little bit playing with the height and width properties will solve it.

---

### UPDATE - 20 November 2019

Change the JavaScript code to:

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('mycanvas').getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://swiftinit.net/swiftapps/Custom/assets/images/frameimages/43378.png';

// The number (50) here is for displaying the shadowblur ( left, right, top, bottom + 25 )
ctx.canvas.width  = img.width + 50;
ctx.canvas.height = img.height + 50;

// Shadow
ctx.shadowColor = 'red';
ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;

// Draw image on load
img.onload = function() {  
  ctx.drawImage(img, 20, 20);
}
```

Check the code in action at [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tmach/pen/KKKJMwE)

Comment: Thanks but I need that canvas to be saved so CSS will not work

Comment: What do you mean by saved, if you want to get the same result in canvas with JS, you can do the same but with canvas.style.property. I can give an other solution if you can explain the saved canvas part.

Comment: thank you very much. I mean I want to save the border image with shadow blur as base 64 image(canvas.todataURL- will do the job as long as shadow is part of canvas-not css)

Comment: Ok I understand, I have tried a lot of things but getting the border as a base64 didn't worked. I will check later if there is an other way.

Comment: I can make it work, the issue is my codepen has image cutoff. I just need help in getting that fixed. I know how to get base 64.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please try it, for me it worked.

Comment: I do not want to use css. I need border image inside canvas working without image cutoff. Css works but when I export it does not.

Comment: I think I found the solution now. Check the update of 20 november 2019. This seems like what you want. (Note: if you don't see anything in codepen, add some html text and the image will refresh and display).